# Quotation reference: "functions which can be evaluated under 1 sec are as good as analytically available"

Tags: physics, reference-request, quote, computation

I have a vague memory of a (possibly-apocryphal) quote by a physicist (I remember it as being Giorgio Parisi, which could be wrong), saying something to the effect of

> "any function which can be evaluated by a computer in under 1 second should be considered as `analytically available'"

My question is: can anybody corroborate the existence of such a quote, and if so, is there a reference for it?